# Probability distribution in $L_p$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, lp-spaces

I am stuck on this exercise.

Let $F(x) = 1-1/x^a$ for $x\geq 1$ be a distribution.
For which values of $a$, $F(x) \in L_p$?

I tried to study vários integral functions, but I do not really know how to solve it.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X\sim F$ i.e let $X$ have distribution function $F$. Then $X\geq 0$ with probability one. To compute the moments of $X$ we can use the tail formula, namely,
\begin{align}
EX^p=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}P(X>x)\, dx&=\int_0^1px^{p-1}\, dx+p\int_1^\infty\frac{x^{p-1}}{x^a}\, dx\\
&=1+p\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1+a-p}}\, dx
\end{align}
which is finite iff $a-p>0$ i.e $a>p$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why to see if it is in $L_p$ we have to compute the moments?